# How to show that the ordinary quiver of a semisimple algebra is a quiver consisting of isolated points?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, quiver

It is said that the ordinary quiver of a semisimple algebra is a quiver consisting of isolated points? How to prove this result? Thank you very much.

Edit: the ordinary quiver is the quiver defined on page 59 of [the book](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/algebra/elements-representation-theory-associative-algebras-techniques-representation-theory-volume-1).

Comment: What is the definition of the ordinary quiver of an algebra? (I could look it up but I'd like to know what definition you're using, in case there are multiple equivalent definitions).

Comment: @user73985, thank you very much. I will edit the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to that definition, the arrows between points correspond to elements in the basis of $e_a(rad(A)/rad(A)^2)e_b$. In a semisimple ring, $rad(A)=\{0\}$, so such a basis would be empty.

So there are no arrows between distinct points.